# Does any infinite set contain an element that is not uniquely definable?

Tags: logic, set-theory, nonstandard-analysis

#### Background/Motivation

My framework is first order logic and ZF.

A uniquely definable set is one uniquely satisfying a predicate, for instance, the empty set is uniquely defined by the unary predicate $∀y.(y \notin x)$.

When reading about internal set theory (IST), I learnt that

- every uniquely definable set is standard
- every infinite set contains a non-standard element

I can conclude that every infinite set must have an element that is not uniquely definable. Since IST is a conservative extension of ZF, I would expect the same to be true in ZF. Sadly, I didn't find any sources on this. And since the predicate ‘‘uniquely definable’’ cannot really be formulated in ZF, I do not really know how to go about proving this.

#### Question

Does every infinite set have an element that is not uniquely definable in ZF, and how can I prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Math.SE!

**I.** The assertion that *every set uniquely definable by a ZF-formula is standard in IST* (which you pithily, but possibly even more confusingly, summarize as "every uniquely definable set is standard") is a convenient informal summary of the following fact about IST:

> For all ZF-formulas $\varphi(x)$ in one free variable $x$, if $\exists! x. \varphi(x)$ is a theorem of IST, then $\forall x. \varphi(x) \rightarrow st(x)$ is also a theorem of IST.

In your reasoning, you pretend that this fact is an actual implication saying "if the set $x$ is uniquely definable then it's standard" inside IST. Then you pretend that you can take the contrapositive of this implication to get that "if the set $x$ is non-standard then it's not uniquely definable". You then combine this with "every infinite set contains a non-standard element" (which, unlike the previous assertion, is a genuine theorem of IST) to get the fake conclusion that "every infinite set contains an element that is not uniquely definable".

But you cannot conclude that every infinite set must have an element that is not uniquely definable, since the highlighted fact above is **not** in fact an implication of the form $$\forall x. \mathrm{uniquely\_definable}(x) \rightarrow st(x)$$ and therefore does not have a contrapositive asserting that nonstandard elements are not uniquely definable. The issue is not that the predicate "uniquely definable" cannot be formulated in ZF: it's that you never had such a predicate at all. Not in ZF, not in IST. The phrase *every set uniquely definable by a ZF-formula is standard in IST* abbreviated something different.

That should answer your question.

---

**II.** That said, set theorists sometimes talk about so-called pointwise definability, which might seem related to the "unique definability" used above. For the sake of completeness, I'll briefly explain this notion here.

When you have a *model* $(V,\in_V)$ of ZF set theory, it makes sense to talk about pointwise definability of elements of the model: $a \in \mathcal{V}$ is defined by a ZF-formula $\varphi(x)$ if and only if $a$ is the only element of $\mathcal{V}$ that satisfies the formula $\varphi(x)$ when we interpret quantifiers in the formula $\varphi(x)$ as ranging over the set $V$, and occurrences of the symbol $\in$ in the formula $\varphi$ as the relation $\in_V$.

Given a model $(V,\in_V)$ of ZF set theory, the element $a \in V$ is pointwise definable by the ZF-formula $\forall y. \neg (y \in x)$ if and only if $\forall y \in V. \neg (y \in_V a)$ and $\forall x \in V. (\forall y \in V. \neg (y \in_V x)) \rightarrow x = a$ both hold.

Pointwise definability is a property that an element of a model of ZF set theory may have, and not a property that a ZF-set (as in, a set whose existence you prove using the ZF axioms) may have! It depends strongly on the model. E.g. in some models of set theory, the formula "$x$ is the set of all non-principal ultrafilters on $\mathbb{N}$" and the formula "$x$ has no elements" ($\forall y. \neg (y \in x)$) happen to pointwise define the same unique element $a \in \mathcal{V}$. In other models (such as models of ZFC) they don't.

This means that while pointwise definability might seem related at first glance to the "unique definability" posited above, it actually acts in a very different manner: it's only a relationship between elements of a model and ZF-formulas, and we can't talk about a given set being pointwise definable. We can talk about an element of a model being pointwise definable, but that requires fixing a model first.

A pointwise definable model of set theory is a model in which *every* element of the model is definable without parameters by some ZF-formula. It is a non-trivial result that such models can exist, in the sense that if some extension of ZFC set theory proves the consistency of ZF, then it also proves the existence of a pointwise definable model of ZF. If you want to learn more about such models, Hamkins' talks about the [math tea argument](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTcXiutDxYY) provide a good starting point, but I should emphasize that none of the theory about pointwise definability is relevant to working in IST at all.

Comment: Doesn't each standard natural number have a ZF formula that only it satisfies? If IST proves all infinite sets have nonstandard elements, that would suggest IST proves that there are nonstandard naturals. Which seems odd. Is there something wrong with my thinking here?

Comment: @eyeballfrog That's a very good observation: IST does prove that there are nonstandard naturals! The *raison d'etre* of IST is that it lets us do nonstandard analysis without having to manage ultraproducts, superstructures, saturation: the nonstandard elements are always there when we need them.

Comment: Thanks, I was kind of aware I should be careful with the term "uniquely definable", and your response made the problem clear to me. But I'm still wondering about two things: Firstly, you call the assertion ‘‘every set uniquely definable by a ZF-formula is standard in IST ’’ a fact. What is meant by this? For me it is somewhat counterintuitive that I can formulate and argue the validity of facts such as this in some non explicit metalanguage, but at the same time this "metalanguage" is somehow not strong enough to use contraposition. ....

Comment: ... secondly, while I now understand my reasoning over IST was wrong, my question still remains - is "For any infinite set x in ZF, there exists some y ∈x such that there is no ZF-formula φ(t) in one free variable such that ∀t.(φ(t) ⇒ (t=y))  is a theorem of ZF." a "fact" about ZF?

Comment: @GiacomoCozzi: Nothing is stopping you from taking contrapositives in the "metalanguage". If you take the contrapositive of the implication in the highlighted fact above, you get "*if ∀x.φ(x)→st(x) is not a theorem of IST then ∃!x.φ(x) is not a theorem of IST*". As I said, the intended meaning of the utterance "every set uniquely definable by a ZF-formula is standard in IST" *is* the highlighted fact above. The meaning of that utterance is *not* an implication of the form $\forall x. \mathrm{uniquely\_definable}(x) \rightarrow st(x)$ and there is no predicate $\mathrm{uniquely\_definable}(x)$.

Comment: Alas, the question does not remain: "*For any infinite set x in ZF, there exists some y ∈x such that there is no ZF-formula φ(t) in one free variable such that ∀t.(φ(t) ⇒ (t=y)) is a theorem of ZF*" is not well-formed. What is $y$ there? In one case it occurs as a set (an arbitrary element of some other set $x$), in another as part of a ZF-formula `∀t.(φ(t) ⇒ (t=y))`. But ZF-formulas contain only variable symbols, logical symbols (connectives, quantifiers, equality), and the membership relation symbol $\in$; an arbitrary set $y$ is going to be neither of these things.